# Run aggregate function on foreign key table

Tags: django, django-models

```
models.py
class Contest(models.Model):
    sport = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contest = models.ManyToManyField(Contest)

class Entry(models.Model):
    num_entries = models.IntegerField()
    player = models.ForeignKey('Player',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can I do a lookup to find a player based on a sport and then run the aggregate function on the profit entry in the Entries table.  This was the type of approach I wanted to take:

```
from .models import *
from django.db.models import Avg

player = Player.objects.filter(name='Player A').filter(contest__sport='nba').aggregate(Avg(entries__num_entries))
```

Comment: Your `Entries` model doesn't make much sense. A player already has multiple entries through the reverse foreign key relationship, so there is no need for a field like `num_entries` and apart from that it doesn't store any additional information. What does this model represent? A model usually is not a plural of something, because it defines one single line in a table. The table is your entries but the model defines one single entry. So it's name should be `Entry`.

Comment: My models contain more fields but for the sake of simplicity I posted the bare minimum.  Your right, it should be Entry rather than Entries.

Comment: But why should an `Entry` model have a field `num_entries`? That makes no sense. Please explain what an entry represents.

Comment: Im trying to filter all the num_entries of a specific player for a specific sport and run the aggregate function on it.

Comment: num_entries is a number from 1-100

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let a player have multiple entries, your models should look like this:

```
from django.db import models


class Contest(models.Model):
    sport = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contests = models.ManyToManyField(Contest)

class Entry(models.Model):
    # some entry fields

    # every entry has one player connected, so every player can have multiple entries (One to N). The reverse field of the player will be called "entries"
    player = models.ForeignKey('Player',on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='entries')
```

Then you can count the number of entries of a player like this:

```
from .models import Player
from django.db.models import Count

aggregate = Player.objects.filter(name='Player A', contests__sport__in=['nba']).aggregate(num_entries=Count(entries))
print(aggregate['num_entries'])
```

Or even easier, you could do this:

```
from .models import Entry

num_entries = Entry.objects.filter(player__name='Player A', player__contests__sport__in=['nba']).count()
```

Comment: I need to grab the actual value in the field num_entries

Comment: I don't think so ([XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Having a model that is called a plural of something is an indicator for having the wrong thought process behind it. Could you explain what an entry represents?

Comment: Im trying to filter all the num_entries of a specific player for a specific sport and run the aggregate function on it

Comment: I see. But i think that trying to do that is already based on another problem that is your models aren't correctly modeled. ([XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: That is highly likely! I contemplated this model for a day and i thought I got it right but apparently I didn't.

Comment: So if you could add an explanation to your question of what entities you have we could maybe figure out how to model that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Because of how the ORM works, you'll probably need to reverse the query:

```
player = Player.objects.aggregate(Avg(entries__num_entries)).filter(name='Player A').filter(contest__sport='nba')
```

instead of:

```
Player.objects.filter(name='Player A').filter(contest__sport='nba').aggregate(Avg(entries__num_entries))
```

In the former your query basically says "Filter by NBA, then aggregate" while the latter says "Aggregate, then filter"

Comment: putting the entries__num_entries as the function parameter doesn't work since its expecting  a field name.  That was what I tried to do and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
Player.objects.filter(name='Player A').filter(contest__sport='nba').aggregate(Avg('entry__num_entries'))
```